# Problema contando posts en una categoría en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, count

Estoy usando este código para contar categorías dentro de un post y cuando en la categoría hay más de 5 posts el contador deja de funcionar.

```
   <?php $posts = get_posts('post_type=proyectos&category=13'); 
$count = count($posts); 
echo $count; 
?>
```

¿Algúna ayuda?

Gracias
Laura

Comment: Please note this is StackOverflow **en español**. So, please, consider translating your question or posting it at main https://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar el parámetro

`'posts_per_page' => 50`

Te quedaría de esta forma

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 50, 'post_type'=> 'proyectos', 'category' => 13 );
$posts = get_posts( $args );
$count = count($posts); 
echo $count; 
?>
```

Si quieres mostrar todos coloca -1 en posts_per_page

Comment: Solucionado! Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Perfecto!, márcalo como solucionado, saludos